# Trigger a System.exit() after Threads finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I launch multiple threads from a class with a main method,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= ALimit - 1; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        Thread myThread= new Thread(myThreadImplementsRunnable);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

After the thread finishes their work, the main thread is still running. if I call a System.exit(0) after the for loop, my threads won't complete their execution, in fact, they will not even start.
Is there a way to trigger a System.exit(0) after all threads finish their execution, without calling the **join()** method on each thread?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use callable https://dzone.com/articles/java-callable-future-understanding

Comment: why you want to force JVM with System.exit(0) ... any reasons?

Comment: I am editing an existing batch on production environment, and i don't want my java process to hold resources after the job is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ExecutorService and thread pool. Do not forget to shut it down. See the example here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html.

E.g.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    String name = "DefaultName";

    public MyRunnable(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + "# My Name: " + name);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        pool.execute(new MyRunnable("John"));
        pool.execute(new MyRunnable("Jimm"));
        pool.execute(new MyRunnable("Billy"));
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Once all yor threads are done, your main method is finished and the execution is completed.

Comment: `shutdown` - This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.  Use `{@link #awaitTermination awaitTermination}`to do that.

Comment: You have to read it more carefully "The shutdown() method will allow previously submitted tasks to execute before terminating, while the shutdownNow() method prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks."

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of ways to do this.

**1. join all spawned threads. (oh right, you didn't want this, skip to 2)**

This means keeping a reference to all these threads :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[ALimit];  // array to keep track of our threads, or we could use a Collection
    for (int i = 0; i < ALimit; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        Thread myThread= new Thread(myThreadImplementsRunnable);
        threads[i] = myThread; // remember it
        myThread.start();
    }
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.join(); // wait until the thread finishes, will return immediately if it's already finished.
    }
    System.exit(0); // all threads have finished, frankly it's a bit superfluous now.
}
```

**2. Use a CountDownLatch :**

A `CountDownLatch` is basically a count down, and threads can wait for the count down to reach 0. So if each threads that finishes counts down, the main can wait for 0;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch finishedRunning = new CountDownLatch(ALimit);  // Latch with ALimit countdowns needed to flip
    for (int i = 0; i < ALimit; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        Thread myThread= new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                myThreadImplementsRunnable.run();
            } finally {
                finishedRunning.countDown(); // one less to wait for, in a finally block, so exceptions don't mess up our count
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
    finishedRunning.await(); // waits until the count is 0
    System.exit(0); // all threads have finished, frankly it's a bit superfluous now.
}
```

**3. Use an ExecutorService and shutdown :**

An `ExecutorService` manages the threads for you, you can execute tasks, then simply wait for the `ExecutorService` to terminate;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ALimit);
    for (int i = 0; i < ALimit; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        executorService.execute(myThreadImplementsRunnable);
    }
    executorService.shutdown(); // will stop accepting new tasks, but all submitted tasks so far, will still be executed
    boolean terminated = executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // we have to specify a timeout, returns a boolean which we can use to test whether it timed out or not, to maybe try and force termination
    if (!terminated) {
        // try and force things? Shut down anyway? log and wait some more?
    }
    System.exit(0); // all threads have finished, frankly it's a bit superfluous now.
}
```

**4. Use an ExecutorService and futures (this is really like joining all threads again, so you may want to skip this) :**

An `ExecutorService` manages the threads for you, you can submit tasks, keep track of the returned `Future`s, then simply wait for the result of each `Future` to arrive;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Set<Future<?>> futures = new HashSet<>();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ALimit);
    for (int i = 0; i < ALimit; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        Future<?> future = executorService.submit(myThreadImplementsRunnable);
        futures.add(future); // remember the future, pun intended ;)
    }
    executorService.shutdown(); // make sure the services terminates its threads when they're no longer needed.
    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // task failed with an exception : e.getCause() to see which
        }
    }
    System.exit(0); // all threads have finished, frankly it's a bit superfluous now.
}
```

A variation on this is to wrap the `ExecutorService` in a `CompletionService`, which will return you the `Future`s in the order they finish :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ALimit);
    CompletionService<Void> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(executorService);
    for (int i = 0; i <= ALimit - 1; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        completionService.submit(myThreadImplementsRunnable, null);
    }
    executorService.shutdown(); // make sure the services terminates its threads when they're no longer needed.
    for (int i = 0; i < ALimit; i++) {
        Future<?> future = completionService.take();
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // task failed with an exception : e.getCause() to see which
        }
    }
    System.exit(0); // all threads have finished, frankly it's a bit superfluous now.
}
```

**5. Use CompletableFutures**

Java 8 brought us `CompletableFuture`s, which allow us to use running tasks as building blocks. We can simply build a `CompletableFuture` represents all of our async tasks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    CompletableFuture<?>[] completableFutures = new CompletableFuture<?>[ALimit];
    for (int i = 0; i <ALimit; i++) {
        MyThreadImplementsRunnable myThreadImplementsRunnable= new MyThreadImplementsRunnable();
        completableFutures[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(myThreadImplementsRunnable);
    }
    CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures);

    try {
        all.get(); // get the 'combined' result
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // task failed with an exception : e.getCause() to see which
    }

    System.exit(0); // all threads have finished, frankly it's a bit superfluous now.
}
```

**Conclusion**

`CountDownLatch` is probably what you want, it's simple, and there's a minimal overhead.

`ExecutorService` is what a professional would use, it clearly separates the notion of thread and task, offers the option of working with `Future`s, which you can cancel and which offers exception handling for the individual tasks. Threads can be reused, and the amount of threads can be tailored, independently of the number of tasks. But all this may simply be overkill.

`CompletionService` is ideal for when you need to handle finishing of tasks as soon as they are finsihed.

`CompletableFuture` offers the simplicity of `CountDownLatch`, but threads are managed for you.